# Angular 6 Material <mat-select> multiple set default value using form control

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, form-control

I am using form control here is code for my html component

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping.value}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And my ts file is

```js
export class SelectMultipleExample {
   toppings = new FormControl();
  toppingList: any[] = [
      { id:1,value:"test 1"},
      { id:2,value:"test 2"},
      { id:3,value:"test 4"},
      { id:4,value:"test 5"},
      { id:5,value:"test 6"},
      { id:6,value:"test 7"}
    ];

  

  constructor(){
    this.bindData();
  }

  bindData(){
    const anotherList:any[]=[
      { id:1,value:"test 1"},
      { id:2,value:"test 2"}
      ]

      this.toppings.setValue(anotherList)
  }
}
```

I want to set default value for mat select , any help how to achieve this will be great. I want to set multiple default value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that your options are objects. In order for the selections to be applied, the selected objects must be the same objects as the ones used for the options. Revise your code as follows:

```
export class SelectMultipleExample {
    toppings = new FormControl();
    toppingList: any[] = [
        { id:1,value:"test 1"},
        { id:2,value:"test 2"},
        { id:3,value:"test 4"},
        { id:4,value:"test 5"},
        { id:5,value:"test 6"},
        { id:6,value:"test 7"}
    ];

    constructor(){
        this.bindData();
    }

    bindData() {
        const anotherList: any[] = [
            this.toppingList[0],
            this.toppingList[1]
        ]

        this.toppings.setValue(anotherList)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide HTML also because it's a bit confusing.

Comment: No change to the HTML - use the original.

Comment: @G.Tranter i am populating list with api data because i am binding ``toppingList`` on ngInit so, when i get ``toppingList[0]`` and  ``toppingList[1]`` in ``bindData()`` than i am getting error property undefined.

Comment: `bindData()` is called from the constructor, which runs before `ngOnInit()`. Try calling `bindData()` after you data has been populated.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <mat-form-field>
 <mat-label>Select Global Markets</mat-label>
 <mat-select [formControl]="globalmarketCategory" multiple >
 <mat-option *ngFor="let list of toppingList" [value]="list">{{list.value}}</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

```
export class SelectMultipleExample {
    globalmarketCategory= new FormControl();
    toppingList: any[] = [
                        { id:1,value:"test 1"},
                        { id:2,value:"test 2"},
                        { id:3,value:"test 4"},
                        { id:4,value:"test 5"},
                        { id:5,value:"test 6"},
                        { id:6,value:"test 7"}
                        ];


    list = []
    constructor(){
        const anotherList:any[]=[  
                                { id:1,value:"test 1"},
                                { id:2,value:"test 2"}
                                ]
        this.globalmarketCategory.setValue(anotherList);
    }
}
```

Comment: @palani also add description what is difference in your code with the accepted once

Comment: I have included both ui and typescript, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `compareWith` attribute of `mat-select`. See that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57169425/1191125

Answer (score 0):

Use compareWith function while using multiple.

so HTML will look like

```
 <mat-form-field>
  <mat-select
    [compareWith]="compareFn"
    [(ngModel)]="theArrayofSelectedValues">
       <mat-option  *ngFor="let obj of listOfObjs" [value]="obj">
          {{ obj.name }}
       </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in TS compareFn

```
compareFn(o1: any, o2: any) {
  if(o1.id == o2.id )
  return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by [G. Tranter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9226213/g-tranter) gave the correct answer.

Based on their answer, I created the following more detailed example (which might be closer to a real-world implementation of this functionality):

**toppings.html**:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select Your Favorite Topping(s)</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Topping(s)" [formControl]="ToppingsControl" required multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let t of AllToppings" [value]="t">{{t.Name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**toppings.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import ITopping from 'src/app/interfaces/topping-dto';

@Component({
  selector: 'toppings',
  templateUrl: './toppings.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toppings.css']
})
export default class SelectMultipleExample {

  protected ToppingsControl: FormControl<Array<ITopping>> = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
  protected AllToppings: Array<ITopping> = [];

  public constructor() {

    // These values can be injected, pulled from a database, etc.
    this.AllToppings.push({ Id: 1, Name: 'Sprinkles' });
    this.AllToppings.push({ Id: 2, Name: 'Hot Fudge' });
    this.AllToppings.push({ Id: 3, Name: 'Whipped Cream' });
    this.AllToppings.push({ Id: 4, Name: 'Crushed Nuts' });
    this.AllToppings.push({ Id: 5, Name: 'Maraschino Cherries' });

    // Get a reference to the objects that are initially selected by default
    let selectedToppings: Array<ITopping> = [
      this.AllToppings[0],
      this.AllToppings[1]
    ];

    // Set the value of the control to be the selected objects
    this.ToppingsControl.setValue(selectedToppings);
  }

}
```

**topping-dto.ts**:

```
interface ITopping {
  Id: number,
  Name: string
}
export default IClientDto;
```