# Checking and Uncheckind a Checkbox according to its value

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular, checkbox

I need your help, guys!

I am developing a User Administrator for a forums app with Angular. In a section I have an Angular Material multi option select like this:

[image]

I am getting the options on the select from my MySQL DB, each option is a field or column in my DB, I am also bringing the value of each column in each user register, for example, "autoevaluacion" = true.

What I want to achieve is that every checkbox in the multi option select get checked if the value is true or get in blank if its false.

How can I do that?

I tried to do it with the following code but checkboxes don't get checked, just the option appears as you can see in the previous pic.

HTML

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="foros">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center;align-items: center">Foros</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-form-field>
         <mat-label>Foros</mat-label>
         <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
           <mat-option *ngFor="let dato of element.optionsForos" [value]="dato.val">{{dato.label}}</mat-option>
         </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

TS File

```
public transfromData(datos: Array<any>){

    return datos.map(dato => {

      dato["optionsForos"] = [
        {
          val: dato.autoevaluacion,
          label: "Autoevaluacion"
        },
        {
          val: dato.rt_funcionarios,
          label: "RT_Funcionarios"
        },
        {
          val: dato.reporteadores,
          label: "Reporteadores"
        },
        {
          val: dato.reporteadores_gerentes,
          label: "Reporteadores_Gerentes"
        },
        {
          val: dato.rt_gerentes,
          label: "RT_Gerentes"
        },
        {
          val: dato.contrato_funcionarios,
          label: "Contratos_Funcionarios"
        },
        {
          val: dato.rt_jefes,
          label: "RT_Jefes"
        },
        {
          val: dato.contrato_gerentes,
          label: "Contrato_Gerentes"
        },
      ]   ;

      console.log(dato)
      return dato;

    });

  }

  public async obtenerUsuarios(){
    let data;
    this.tablaUsuarios = await this.forosServicio.getUsuarios(data);
    console.log(this.tablaUsuarios)
    this.tablaUsuarios = this.transfromData(this.tablaUsuarios);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.tablaUsuarios);
    console.log(this.dataSource)
  }
```

Comment: Check this question, he have the same problem [Angular + Material - How to handle multiple checkboxes with formgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542801/angular-6-material-mat-select-multiple-set-default-value-using-form-control)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a value array to the formControl that you have in your case `toppings`, But the problem is you are passing all select's option values are `true` or `false` (non unique)

Modify your template to hold the value object for each option as unique (we are going to use label which is unique for the options label and value both)

```
<mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let dato of element.optionsForos" [value]="dato.label">{{dato.label}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

In your typescript code manually assign the values

```
public async obtenerUsuarios(){
  let data;
  this.tablaUsuarios = await this.forosServicio.getUsuarios(data);
  console.log(this.tablaUsuarios)
  this.tablaUsuarios = this.transfromData(this.tablaUsuarios);
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.tablaUsuarios);
  console.log(this.dataSource)

  // Here manually filter all true `val` map them with the attribute `label` and assign to Select's formControl value `toppings`
  this.toppings.setValue(this.tablaUsuarios.optionsForos.filter(opt => opt.val).map(opt => opt.label));

}
```

So in your code the value of the option is the `label` attribute from your data structure, and in this above code we are filtering what values are true based on the `val` attribute and then outputting an array with only those labels which are true and feed to toppings formControl.

Your select needs a value based on your options. In your code your options are either true or false but not unique but your labels are, so I used labels as their values for options (display and value both are using attribute label)

Hope this works out for you