# Not able to update my multiple mat-select with new selection

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I would appreciate any help.
I using Angular reactive form and material design mat-select with **multiple** selection.
The select box display a list of country and their respective flag:

```
>   **spokenLangs**: any[] = [
>             {lang: 'Hebrew',  flag: 'icons8-israel-48.png'},
>             {lang: 'English', flag: 'icons8-great-britain-48.png'},
>             {lang: 'Russian', flag: 'icons8-russian-federation-48.png'},
>             {lang: 'French',  flag: 'icons8-france-48.png'},
>             {lang: 'Italian', flag: 'icons8-italy-48.png'},
>             {lang: 'Spanish', flag: 'icons8-spain-flag-48.png'},
>             {lang: 'German',  flag: 'icons8-germany-48.png'},
>             {lang: 'Chinese', flag: 'icons8-china-48.png'},
>           ];
```

I am able to initialize my mat-select with a predifined selection of choosen lang among spokenLangsArray:

```
this.selectedLangs = [{lang: 'English', flag: 'icons8-great-britain-48.png'}, {lang: 'German',  flag: 'icons8-germany-48.png'}]

this.clientForm = this.fb.group(
  **spokenLangs**: [this.**selectedLangs**]
})
```

My problem occur when I updating my matSelect with other predifined selection received from server.

```
this.**selectedLangs** = this.selectedClientData.spokenLangs;

this.clientForm.patchValue({**spokenLangs**: this.**selectedLangs**});
```

**

- my mat-select remains with no selections.

**

```
<form [formGroup]="clientForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate >
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="spokenLangs">
  <mat-label>Spoken Languages</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="**spokenLangs**" placeholder="Select Language" 
              [(ngModel)]="**selectedLangs**" **multiple**>
   <mat-select-trigger>
    <img height="25px" *ngFor="let currLang of **selectedLangs**"  style="margin-right: 
         1em;" src="../../../../assets/icons/flags/{{currLang.flag}}">
   </mat-select-trigger>
   <mat-option *ngFor="let elem of **spokenLangsArray**" [value]="elem">
     <img height="25px" src="../../../../assets/icons/flags/{{elem.flag}}">
   </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: the problem is that the "objects" are not equal -yes, his properties are equals but they are not the same object. You need use "compareWith". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477167/use-comparewith-function-from-angular-material-mat-select-component-with-linked

Comment: Many thanks. after adding the compareWith method it works correctly!!!