# dropdown select value from nested array object in mat-select angular material 10

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am getting response from an API that contains, nested array of objects.

I want to use mat-select to show which options are available and also show the selected option when user opens the page for the first time.

```
    <div *ngFor="let subgroup of maingroup">
// some items here
    <div *ngFor="let item of subgroup.child">
// some other items here as well 
      <mat-label> {{item.description}}</mat-label>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" >
        <mat-select>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of item.optionsarray [value]="option">
            {{option.description}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select> </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

so my problem is, "*ngFor="let option of item.optionsarray" this is the options object (array), and inside this object I have different attributes, including

selected: true/false

attribute, so that means that object should be shown as selected when user visits the page, also when they make another selection i need to update selected object as well.

and there is only one element(object) in the array have selected attribute as true, others are false.

How can I implement this?

in the mat-select tag i tried to use [value], but that is outside of the last ngfor statement, so i cant figure out how to implement this solution.

Comment: You need to use either a Reactive or Template-driven form: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: It seems this solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477167/use-comparewith-function-from-angular-material-mat-select-component-with-linked